# Javascript function to add margin to <p> tags depending on new lines

Tags: javascript

I have a text with new lines on javascript. I used `text.split('\n')` to split it into an array.

So what I have now is this:

```
[
  'Hello world',
  '',
  '',
  'This is the first line',
  '',
  'This is the second line',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  'This is the last line'
]
```

I want each new line to be 5px of margin, so I want to convert it to this:

```html
<p style={{ marginBottom: '10px' }}>Hello world</p>
<p style={{ marginBottom: '5px' }}>This is the first line</p>
<p style={{ marginBottom: '20px' }}>This is the second line</p>
<p>This is the last line</p>
```

I think I can write a function to do it like this:

1. Start an accumulator in 0.
2. Loop through the array, from the top down, if you find text, set the marginBottom with the value of accumulator * 5px and wrap that text into a `<p>`, then reset the accumulator to 0.
3. If you find empty string, then add 1 to the accumulator.

Maybe there's a better way of doing it?

Comment: You can start from the end of the array. The logic might seem simpler that way.

Comment: Instead of writing too much logic you can simply do it CSS !  add a custom html tag with 5 px margin ...

Comment: Now I think, would it be better so have more html tags or a more "complex" logic? I already made the function and it works...

Answer (score 0):

Using js to set styles can be tricky  also  by your method it would lead to complex calculations .. Leave to css and use html tags !

See example =>

**HTML**

```
<div id="main"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.spacer {
  display: block;
  height: 5px; /* Adjust the margin by changing height */
}
```

**JS**

```
const main = document.querySelector('#main')

let array = [
  'Hello world',
  '',
  '',
  'This is the first line',
  '',
  'This is the second line',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  'This is the last line'
]

let html = "";
array.forEach(val => val === "" ? html += "<div class='spacer'></div>": html += `<p> ${val} </p>`)

main.innerHTML = html;
```

Comment: @nick By using css your at advantage as you can change the height ( margin reference )  easily without going to change in js !  Live example [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y3fhuod6/1/)